Mistakenly launched, but did't carry out an OS upgrade (Monterey>Sonoma). How do I get rid of the macOS installer boot menu item?
I'm running Monterey (with OCLP) on a Late 2012 Mac mini "Core i7" (Intel Ivy Bridge). The model identifier is Macmini6,2. The macOS upgrade got mistakenly launched from macOS System Preferences.
Fortunately, the multi-boot setup on the machine (Linux/macOS/Windows) makes the boot selection screen (provided by OCLP loader) appear every time, and I'm able to boot into and use Monterey  (no installer) just fine, but there's a new "macOS installer" boot menu item now.
Is there a way to get rid of it? I see that there are extra snapshots (bless and MSUPrepareUpdate) on the system volume, but I'm not familiar with how these work during OS upgrades/for booting.
The installer boot item is not listed in the Startup Disk preference pane.
 % diskutil ap listsnapshots /
Snapshots for disk3s5s1 (4 found)
|
+-- C20C334E-B5E6-4930-9A95-6EBFB4AFC239
|   Name:        com.apple.os.update-0B1771E5231A28D50DDD7496C67295FC768D3B7510559D513248DDDCA157F755
|   XID:         2298186
|   Purgeable:   No
|
+-- D079A603-8A7B-43A2-B650-4669ED209C67
|   Name:        com.apple.bless.D1C4ABE7-B231-4DF3-ACCB-43B0A83A03EB
|   XID:         2299238
|   Purgeable:   Yes
|
+-- 61257838-DA97-4963-98C1-9E5E47B613CB
|   Name:        com.apple.bless.6A90AD6F-2A91-4577-A32F-EE7F0750E0D9
|   XID:         2537559 (Will root to (boot from) this snapshot)
|   Purgeable:   Yes
|
+-- 159A1187-74A8-4C2E-B33F-F852D05E6A02
    Name:        com.apple.os.update-MSUPrepareUpdate
    XID:         2613235
    Purgeable:   No
    NOTE:        This snapshot limits the minimum size of APFS Container disk3

